# Deploying a Spring app to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services

I'm new to Spring and built a simple Springboot app that has a couple of endpoints and stores data in a mysql database. It is now time for me to deploy it to AWS. I setup a beanstalk instance, uploaded my war file, and also setup a rds db instance with mysql. When I try to visit one of my endpoints using my environment url/(the endpoint), I'm getting a 404 error. I know the endpoints work because when I ran the project locally, I tested them.

I suspect the issue is the Spring datasource url I have configured in my project. When I was running locally, I had the url set to the following: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/exampleDb

I tried changing the url to the following: jdbc:mysql://(my aws environment url):3306/ebdb but I still get the same error.

What should I change the datasource url to? Any ideas? I'm new to Spring and AWS, so this has really been a roadblock.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't make guesses as to what could be wrong. View the server logs and see what the actual error is. It sounds like Tomcat is failing to start your webapp for some reason, and the actual error should be in the log. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Comment: First check if your tomcat is running fine on server then login to server using putty check the credential you provided for mysql is correct or not because you used correct configuration to connect to mysql database

Comment: I checked to make sure the mysql credentials are correct. Still haven't figured out how to solve this issue.